# containers and operators in c++

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading

I'm requested to implement a simple algorithm which returns a set.
It recevies a container (of stl) and an object which implements the binary () opertor. This operator receives two containers and returns a boolean. The returned set will contain every element of the original container which follows some rules.
So my algo looks like this:

```
template<typename Container, typename T, typename Object>
  std::set<T> algo(Container<T>& con, Object obj) {
      std::set<T> out;
      std::vector<T> one;
      std::vector<T> two;
      bool flag_passed_x = false;

    for (typename Container::iterator i = con.begin(); i != con.end(); ++i) {
        one.clear();
        two.clear();
        for (typename Container::iterator j = con.begin(); j != con.end();
            ++j) {
        // split the container
        if (i == j)
            flag_passed_x = true;

        if (!flag_passed_x)
            one.insert(*j);
        else
            two.insert(*j);
        }
        if (obj(one, two)) {
            out.insert(*i);
        }
    }

return out;
}
```

I also tried the implement a test, by creating the class Kuku whic implements the operator () and send a vector to that algorithm which contains the numbers 0-9.

```
template<typename Container>
class Kuku {
bool operator()(const Container& low, const Container& high) {
    for(typename Container::iterator i = low.begin(); i != low.end(); ++i) {
        for(typename Container::iterator j = high.begin(); j != high.end(); ++j) {
            if ((int) *j > (int) *i)
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
    }
};
```

Tried to call it with:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    Kuku<std::vector<int>> kik;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    line 58 ---> std::set<int> a = algo(v, kik);
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting errors that I can't get rid of:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
no matching function for call to 'algo(std::vector<int>&,      Kuku<std::vector<int> >&)'   a.cpp   /dry4   line 58 C/C++ Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::set<#1,std::less<#1>,std::allocator<#1>> algo(#0 &, #2)
'   a.cpp   /dry4   line 58 Semantic Error
```

Comment: Just for your information you don't need the `T` type in your template list. All standard containers and container adaptors have a `value_type` alias that you can use to get the contained type.

Comment: More related to your problem, `Container` should be the full container type, not the template. Take a look at how you use it in the `Kuku` class.

Comment: I don't know what compiler you are using, but gcc gives you a very straightforward message: `error: 'Container' is not a template`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is riddled with errors

You neglected to mention the first error you actually get:

```
error: 'Container' is not a template
std::set<T> algo(Container<T>& con, Object obj)
```

You can fix this by modifying your template arguments:

```
template<template<class...> class Container, typename T, typename Object>
std::set<T> algo(Container<T>& con, Object obj) {
```

Next, you try to `insert` into `vectors` with a value. Use `push_back` instead:

```
if (!flag_passed_x)
      one.push_back(*j);
else
      two.push_back(*j);
```

Next, you have an incomplete iterator declaration for your `Container`. You need to qualify it as `Container<T>::iterator`

```
for (typename Container<T>::iterator i = con.begin(); i != con.end(); ++i) {
// ...
    for (typename Container<T>::iterator j = con.begin(); j != con.end();
```

Next, you don't expose `Kuku`'s `operator()` as public:

```
template<typename Container>
class Kuku {
public:
   bool operator()
```

Next, you inadvertently try to get a normal iterator from a `const` container instead of a `const_iterator`:

```
for(typename Container::const_iterator i = low.begin(); i != low.end(); ++i) {
        for(typename Container::const_iterator j = high.begin(); j != high.end(); ++j) {
```

[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZTSF3gih8t2CLzyR)

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. Made some changes to my code, and noticed that it can't deduce T, so added another parameter to algo like this:       std::set<T> algo(Container& con, Object obj, T t)           how can I avoid this?

Comment: @EitanKosman: The code in my link doesn't work for you? Are you using a pre-c++11 compiler? You'd need to change the template to accept another class for the allocator of the vector.  Like `template<template<class, class> class Container, typename Object, class T, class A>
  std::set<T> algo(Container<T, A>& con, Object obj) {` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b887943f965ef52)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is:

```
template<typename Container, typename T, typename Object>
   std::set<T> algo(Container<T>& con, Object obj) {
```

It should be:

```
template<typename Container, typename T, typename Object>
   std::set<T> algo(Container& con, Object obj) {
```

Don't try and make `Container` be a class-template (and that is not how you declare class templates as arguments anyway).  Just let it be a simple class (which may well be generated from a template).  The particular problem is that `std::vector` doesn't have a single template argument - it has at least two (T and allocator), and (at least in older versions of C++) there may be implementation specific additional parameters.  (I don't know whether they removed that in later versions of the standard.)

If you *really* want to make `Container` be a class template, then it needs to be:

```
template<
   template<typename T1, class Allocator = std::allocator<T1>> typename Container, 
   typename T, 
   typename Object>
std::set<T> algo(Container<T>& con, Object obj) {
```

Incidentally, I think your loop could be simplified to:

```
for (auto i = con.begin(); i != con.end(); ++i) {
    const std::vector<T> one(con.begin(), i);
    const std::vector<T> two(i, con.end());
    if (obj(one, two)) {
        out.insert(*i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to understand the loop modification but maybe I miss something. Mine goes [begin, i-1] for one and [i,end] for two. Does it do the same?

Comment: Actually, yours goes [begin,i-1], and [i,end-1].  Or, [begin,i), [i,end) - and that half open format is how the STL (almost) always works.  So, yes - mine does the same.

Comment: Actually, better still.  Use two deques - `one` starts empty, `two` is a copy of the container, then iteratively move an element from the front of `two` to the back of `one`.  That will be O(n) copies rather than O(n²) copies.